# Label does not display text or update text when a specific method is called

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am working with a Visual WebPart (c#) which consists of an UpdatePanel which wraps the contents of the web form.  On this form, within the UpdatePanel, I have an asp.net label which has its text property set based on the outcome of the submit.  It's set to visible after execution, and its forecolor is changed as well depending on error or success.  This works perfectly (text updates/becomes visible) until I decide to call a specific method when the submit button is pressed.  When this method is called, the text property is not updating and the label is not displaying.

I have debugged this process several times and each time I step through the process and see the correct message, see it get applied to the label's text property, and complete but the page is not updated.  I can reproduce the working functionality by commenting out the method call.  No errors are being thrown.  The program appears to execute properly while debugging.

**submit button code excerpt:**

```
try
                {
                    CreateElementOnDestinationWebs(this.ddlSupportedElements.SelectedValue.ToString(), elementName, ref messages);
                    msg = String.Format("<br />We have successfully created your {0}.  Please review the following outcomes: <br /><ul>", this.ddlSupportedElements.SelectedItem.Text);
                    foreach (string m in messages)
                    {
                        msg += String.Format("<li>{0}</li>", m);
                    }
                    msg += "</ul>";

                    labelMessages.Text = msg;
                    labelMessages.Visible = true;
                    labelMessages.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen;                        
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    msg = String.Format("<br />An unexpected error occurred while creating the item: {0}", ex.ToString());
                    labelMessages.Text = msg;
                    labelMessages.Visible = true;
                    labelMessages.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Maroon;
                }
```

**CreateElementOnDestinationWebs source:**

```
try
                    {
                        Guid listId = web.Lists.Add(name, "Student work can be submitted here.", SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary);
                        web.Update();

                        SPList newList = web.Lists[listId];
                        newList.OnQuickLaunch = this.checkDropBoxShowOnQuickLaunch.Checked;
                        newList.EnableModeration = true;
                        newList.Update();

                        GrantStudentGroupsContributeRights(web, ref newList, ref msgs);

                        try
                        {
                            DetectAddColumnsToDropbox(web, ref newList, ref msgs);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            msgs.Add("There was an unexpected error while attempting to add the site columns to the library.");
                        }                        

                        msgs.Add(String.Format("Your item: {0}, has been successfully created on site: <a href='{1}' target='_blank'>{2}</a>", name, web.Url, web.Title));
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        msgs.Add(String.Format("An error occurred while creating the document library for student work on site: <a href='{0}' target='_blank'>{1}</a>", web.Url, web.Title));
                    }
```

If the try block containing "DetectAddColumnsToDropbox" is commented out the label (labelMessages) appears correctly.  If not, the label does not appear/update.  The method in question does not update any control or item on the form.

Comment: Can you show the code that you are referencing in your question? also is this particular issue happening when you are doing a PostBack..? Keep in mind that UpdatePanels do `Partial PostBacks`

Comment: Is the button within the update panel ? For me it seems like the buttons post-back does not trigger the update event.. you could even explicitly call the update method of the panel. and do you have nested update panels?

Comment: Yes.  The button is within the update panel.  It is completing the work.  All operations end successfully but the label does not display the text.  The UpdateProgress code fires every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try omitting the inner try/catch or throwing the exception back to the caller method.

Comment: I commented out the inner try block and just left the method call.  This yields the same result unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for taking the time to either comment or attempt to answer this issue.  After continued searching I found a related issue:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5794/trying-to-use-an-spweb-object-that-has-been-closed-or-disposed-and-is-no-longer

The method: DetectAddColumnsToDropbox declared a variable for the rootweb of the site collection the given web was in.  It then disposed the rootweb object.  Turns out, SharePoint does not care for that and a JavaScript error was being thrown.  I took out the dispose (using block) code and everything functions properly with labelMessages.